# Spring MVC CRUD Application using annotation

Tags: spring-mvc

I wanted to learn how to use annotation in `Spring MVC` using annotation.
But apparently the Spring MC Step By Step that is bundled with Spring 2.5 download release
uses concrete Controller hierarchy.

Hopefully somebody could give me a good link where I could learn annotation driven spring mc application.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183553/how-to-lean-spring-mvc-in-3-0/3183650#3183650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Spring 3 sample application repository](http://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples).

For MVC see `mvc-basic` sample, for basic CRUD with MVC check `petclinic`.

**Edit:** [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) on petclinic sample